# TFS - whole project start and end dates with sprints

Tags: tfs, agile, agile-project-management

i am having a TFS 2012 server for managing my project
i have several sprints with same length 2weeks

Is it possible to set a whole project start and end dates ?how can you see the whole project start and end dates with all the sprints informations weather it is ongoing, finished, late.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The sprints should be defined under a parent node. You can set this node's start and end dates just as you would the sprints.

As for seeing information about the project (i.e. whether, or not, it is on-going, finished, late, etc.), depends on which metrics you are looking for. SQL Server Reporting Services contain reports that run off both the Warehouse database and the OLAP cube that resides in Analysis services. The reports are dependent on which process template the project is based off of (Agile, Scrum, CMMI, etc.). Nonetheless, the reports will give you overview information, release burndowns, sprint burndowns, etc.